# How to hit API in RecyclerView for every row by Activity Button event

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I developing an app in which there are many rows in Recyclerview, I have to update the Available quantity of all the rows by Single Button on Activity.When i will click on Confirm All button on Activity it will update all rows one by one.

I have already done the single update by confirm button on every row, but i'm not getting the idea how to do by single click same thing one by one.I'm using Volley here.

User will update Available Qty of all rows at a time & by single tab have to update all the rows.

[image: Image Here]

**My Recycler Adapter:**

```
public class AdjustInventoryAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdjustInventoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
List<AdjustResult> list;
Context context;

public AdjustInventoryAdapter(Context context, List<AdjustResult> result) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list=result;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adjust_inventory_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final AdjustResult listPotn = list.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(listPotn.getName());
    holder.sku.setText(listPotn.getSku());
    holder.upc.setText(listPotn.getUpc());
    holder.availableQty.setText(listPotn.getOnHandQty());


    holder.editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ((AdjustInventory)context).editQuantity(listPotn.getSku(),holder.availableQty.getText().toString().trim(),holder.getPosition());

        }
    });

}




@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView name,sku,upc;
    Button editBtn;
    EditText availableQty;
    ImageView imageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameAdjust);
        sku = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.skuAdjust);
        upc = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.upcAdjust);
        editBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEditAdjust);
        availableQty = (EditText) 
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.availableQtyAdjust);
       // imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgAdjust);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a arraylist for saving editText value of each row:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> wholeQuantity;
```

initialise it in constructor as:

```
 wholeQuantity = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    wholeQuantity.add(list.get(i). getOnHandQty());
```

Do this in "onBindViewHolder" as:

```
  holder.availableQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
              wholeQuantity.set(position,Integer.parseInt(editable.toString());
        }
    });
```

now you create a method :

```
 public void confirmAllQuantity(){

      for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
      {
           ((AdjustInventory)context).editQuantity(list.get(i).getSku(),wholeQuantity.get(i),i);
      }
 }
```

This will do task what you want.

Thanks and happy coding.
 let me know if need more help!!

EDITED::

You are creating recycler view by calling  a this line:

```
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adjustInventoryAdapter);
```

In that class/activity, like you want to conform all edit text value, do code like::

```
  adjustInventoryAdapter.confirmAllQuantity();
```

Comment: Adding a new TextWatcher() for each bind event will hit performance.
Instead, an alternative is to create an arraylist of TextWatchers, with size equal to size of the data.

If the TextWatcher for a particular position is null, initialize it, else use the old textwatcher.

Comment: My Confirm All button is in Activity , How could i perform this by button listner. @ankitpatidar & thanks for reply

Comment: Now you have a Adapter object right?... So call this method by this object after "setAdapter()" anytime

Comment: Sorry, i'm not getting . Can you please edit your answer & also mention  what i have to add where like in Activity or Adapter. Thanks alot @ankitpatidar

Comment: Hope you understand.if not able to ask I will explain

Comment: Inside Adapter where i have to add this line... wholeQuantity = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    wholeQuantity.add(list.get(i). getOnHandQty());

Comment: inside your constructor: public AdjustInventoryAdapter(Context context, List<AdjustResult> result) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list=result;                                                                    
     wholeQuantity = new ArrayList<>(); for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) wholeQuantity.add(list.get(i). getOnHandQty());
}

Comment: No worry brother. Contact me if need more help